# How do you call a "union or group of memories" in a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests

A memory is a representation of the brain about something.
How do you call a union of those representations in a single word?
A union or group of memories is? A scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Engram**

> An *engram* is a unit of cognitive information inside the brain, theorized to be the means by which memories are stored as biophysical or biochemical changes in the brain (and other neural tissue) in response to external stimuli.

(Source: [Engram (neuropsychology)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engram_(neuropsychology)), Wikipedia)

Comment: Wow didn't expect there was a word for it to be honest.

Comment: Chalk it up to my misspent youth, watching Star Trek reruns. See "The Ultimate Computer" (TOS, Season 2, Ep. 24). The M-5 computer was imprinted with Dr. Daystrom's *engrams*, causing it to go berserk.

Comment: But OP wants a group, it seems that *engram* is a unit. And by the definition, I’d take it to mean the basic building blocks of complex memories.

Comment: If "An engram is a unit of cognitive information" then the "cognitive information" *is* a group.

Comment: @rajah9 - So your answer is “Cognitive Information”?  That’s not clear as formatted.

Comment: @Jim, *engram* is my answer. It is a theoretical set or group of memories and memory associations. When a child is given an apple slice for the first time, she may be forming an engram around a crisp, sweet, tangy, red Macintosh apple. Also with the sound of the word. Also with her mom saying, "yum!" The *engram* is formed around this group of sensual distinctives, and is theorized to make lasting changes in the brain. Later the engram might expand in association with an apple tree, apple pie, cinnamon, a record label in the UK, the temptation in the Garden of Eden, and a computer company.

Comment: I see what you’re saying now.  That’s not how I interpreted the definition.

Comment: I read it as being similar to in computing where a *bit* is a unit of information and an engram is therefore equivalent to the smallest unit of human memory.  Complex memories are thus made up of many engrams.  As I understand your line or thinking my whole human existence as I understand it could be one big expanded engram.

Comment: Not a neuroscientist, but as a computer scientist, here's a flawed analogy. The engram is an index to a BLOB in a DB table (so think a 64-bit pointer, not a single bit or byte). Once retrieved, the BLOB contains indices that point to other BLOBs. The engram is neurochemically represented in the brain. "Engrams are sufficient for the memory of an episode, which means that the activation of a specific engram leads to the occurrence of the corresponding memory." (quoted at https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/psychology/engram).